# Cannot train a neural network solving XOR mapping

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I am trying to implement a simple classifier for the XOR problem in Keras. Here is the code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy

X = numpy.array([[1., 1.], [0., 0.], [1., 0.], [0., 1.], [1., 1.], [0., 0.]])
y = numpy.array([[0.], [0.], [1.], [1.], [0.], [0.]])
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=2, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(3, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='softmax'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd)

model.fit(X, y, nb_epoch=20)
print()
score = model.evaluate(X, y)
print()
print(score)
print(model.predict(numpy.array([[1, 0]])))
print(model.predict(numpy.array([[0, 0]])))
```

I tried changing the number of epochs, learning rate, and other parameters. But the error remains constant from the first to the last epoch.

```
Epoch 13/20
6/6 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6667 
Epoch 14/20
6/6 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6667
Epoch 15/20
6/6 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6667
Epoch 16/20
6/6 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6667
Epoch 17/20
6/6 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6667
Epoch 18/20
6/6 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6667
Epoch 19/20
6/6 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6667
Epoch 20/20
6/6 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6667

6/6 [==============================] - 0s

0.666666686535
[[ 1.]]
[[ 1.]]
```

How do you train this network in Keras?

Also, is there a better library for implementing neural networks? I tried PyBrain, but it has been abandoned, tried scikit-neuralnetwork but the documentation is really cryptic so couldn't figure out how to train it. And I seriously doubt if Keras even works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, you have a Dense layer with 1 unit with a softmax activation. The value of such a unit will always be 1.0, so no information can flow from your inputs to your outputs, and the network won't do anything. Softmax is only really useful when you need to generate a prediction of a probability among n classes, where n is greater than 2.

The other answers suggest changes to the code to make it work. Just removing `activation='softmax'` may be enough.

Keras does generally work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the last perceptron in the network without an activation function. I had the same problem and it starts learning when you remove the activation function.

Also, you could try to split the output layer into 2 neurons. And have the output be [0,1] for 0 and [1,0] for one.

However, removing the activation function should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD

X = np.array([[1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0]], dtype='uint8')
y = np.array([[0], [0], [1], [1], [0], [0]], dtype='uint8')


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=2))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd, class_mode="binary")

history = model.fit(X, y, nb_epoch=10000, batch_size=4, show_accuracy=True)

print
score = model.evaluate(X,y)
print
print score
print model.predict(np.array([[1, 0]]))
print model.predict(np.array([[0, 0]]))

# X vs y comparison
print
predictions = model.predict(X)
predictions = predictions.T
predictions = [1 if prediction >= 0.5 else 0 for prediction in predictions[0]]
print predictions
print [int(n) for n in y]
```

Unfortunatelly, I'm beginner in machine learning and I don't know why my code works and your doesn't.

[I used this code.](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/112#issuecomment-156311068)