# Keras neural network outputs same result for every input

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I tried to implement a feedforward neural network.

This is the structure:
Input layer: 8 neurons, Hidden layer: 8 neurons and Output layer: 8 neurons.

The input data are vectors of 8 bits (1 bit for each neuron of the input layer).
The outputs of the neural network are also vectors of 8 bits. So in total the dataset has 256 examples.

Example: if given x = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]

the output must be y = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]

This is the implementation:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np
import random
from math import ceil

#Dimension of layers
dim = 8

#Generate dataset
X = []
for i in range(0,2**dim):
    n = [float(x) for x in bin(i)[2:]]
    X.append([0.]*(dim-len(n))+n)
y = X[:]
random.shuffle(y)
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(dim, input_dim=dim, init='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(dim, init='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(dim, init='normal', activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='SGD', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, y, nb_epoch=1000, batch_size=50, verbose=0)
# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, y)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
output = model.predict(X)

#Make the output binary
for i in range(0, output[:,0].size):
    for j in range(0, output[0].size):
        if output[i][j] > 0.5 or output[i][j] == 0.5:
            output[i][j] = 1
        else:
            output[i][j] = 0
print(output)
```

This is what I get in output:

```
acc: 50.39%
[[ 1.  0.  0. ...,  0.  1.  1.]
[ 1.  0.  0. ...,  0.  1.  1.]
[ 1.  0.  0. ...,  0.  1.  1.]
..., 
[ 1.  0.  0. ...,  0.  1.  1.]
[ 1.  0.  0. ...,  0.  1.  1.]
[ 1.  0.  0. ...,  0.  1.  1.]]
```

It seems that all outputs have the same value. So I don´t know what's wrong about the configuration. I tried this [Cannot train a neural network in keras - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311586/cannot-train-a-neural-network-in-keras) which suggests to remove the activation function at the output layer but when I run this I get all output vectors with this value:

[ 0.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]

Any insights on how to make it work?

Comment: How many times did you tried to rerun this? Maybe using different optimizer or regularization / randomization algorithm might help. It seems that your network is likely to stuck in local minimas.

Comment: I tried to rerun it like 15 times and got the same result. I tried using "Adam" and tried using "relu" activation and it imporved a little bit, now I get different outputs but accuracy still very low (4 out of 256 correct output).

Comment: Have you tried to use e.g. dropout? Or batch normalization?

Comment: Interesting choice of data. You're objective is to learn the shuffling function?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yeah I tried dropout, but doesn't seem to work,

Comment: Yeah, I want the neural network to learn the shuffling function.

Answer (score 12):

I had the very same problem.

I would suggest you to reduce the learning rate for SGD. In my case I had used Adam Optimizer with lr=0.001, but changing to 0.0001 solved the problem.

Default parameters for SGD [are](https://keras.io/optimizers/):

> keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.0, decay=0.0, nesterov=False)

Comment: This solved my problem, which is my CNN produces the same probability distribution for all inputs...confused!

Answer (score 7):

The output is relatively similar to multi-label classification so I would recommend:

1. Change loss function to binary_crossentropy
2. Retain the last activation layer as sigmoid and change the others - relu can be a good choice.
3. Add validation to your "fit" call and increase verbosity - This will allow you to understand how your network changes through the epochs and especially when it over/under fits
4. Add depth to the network until you overfit
5. Add regularization to your network until you don't overfit
6. repeat 4+5

Answer (score 1):

If you tried all the above and it does not work it means
that you try to fit noise, there is no connection/correlation/relevance between your inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was casting the model output to an integer, then de-normalized the output, when I should have been de-normalizing first, and casting to integer afterwards. Because if the model output is in the range (0, 1), then casting it to integer will just turn it to `1`, and then the de-normalized version will always be the same. So

`int(unnormalize(model(input)))`

instead of

`unnormalize(int(model(input)))`